# What does the Assad regime gain from the use of "chemical weapons" on Syrian civilians?

Tags: russian-federation, syria, western-world, chemical-weapons

What does Assad hope to gain from the use of these so called chemical weapons that the west is claiming he's using on his people?

To me it would only make things worse for his regime and give even more reason for western powers to try and topple his regime.